customtkinter: вывод символов в консоль во время набора
Подскажите, как сделать проверку поля entry, чтобы при наборе букв в поле сразу выводить их в консоль?
import customtkinter
from customtkinter import StringVar


class Authorization(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 0), weight=1)
        self.geometry("400+200")
        self.title("")
        self.text_var = StringVar()
        # self.text_var.trace("w", self.checking_field_entry())
        self.put_widgets()

    def checking_field_entry(self):
        login = self.text_var.get()
        print(login)

    def action_btn_signin(self):
        print(self.text_var.get())
    
    def action_btn_registr(self):
        pass

    def put_widgets(self):
        font_entry = ("Arial", 18)
        self.sign_in_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.sign_in_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")
        self.login_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.sign_in_frame, width=200, font=font_entry,textvariable=self.text_var, placeholder_text="login")
        self.login_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10), ipady=5, sticky="ew")

        self.btn_signin = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, width=200, text="войти", corner_radius=24, font=("Arial", 18), command=self.action_btn_signin)
        self.btn_signin.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10), ipady=10, sticky="n")

app = Authorization()
app.mainloop()


Все, нашел, вроде, способ. В tkinter на винде использовал метод trace() но на мак ос он не работал, просто перечеркнут был. Помог метод trace_add().
class Authorization(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0, 0), weight=1)
        self.geometry("400+200")
        self.title("")
        self.text_var = StringVar()
        self.text_var.trace_add("write", self.checking_field_entry)
        # trace("w", self.checking_field_entry())
        self.put_widgets()
    
    def checking_field_entry(self, *args):
        login = self.text_var.get()
        print(login)

